# Engineering dropout achievement: can I power a new weapon?

Tags: achievements, into-the-breach

The Engineering dropout achievement is labelled as follows:

> Finish 3 Corporate Islands without powering a Weapon Modification

Does powering a new weapon (but not its further actual modifications) count as powering a Weapon Modification?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Powering a new weapon is fine, but powering the upgrades isn't.

This was relatively easy to test, since ItB shows which "complete without x" achievements your game is still eligible on the achievements menu. I'll post the screenshots later.

Comment: Thank you, I only thought of this question after a pretty good start with that achievement in mind, so I was unwilling to test it myself :)

Comment: Be careful when testing this - if you power a weapon mod between missions and check the menu, it will show the achievement as still available, but as soon as you enter the next mission the achievement will lock itself. In other words, it's okay to power a weapon mod for this achievement, as long as you un-power it before the mission starts.

Comment: I tested it and I can confirm: powering a weapon is fine :)